# Injecting BsModalService defined in constructor but undefined in the function of the same class

Tags: angular7

I'm injecting the BsModalService in my own provider, on the construction function the bs modal service is defined but in a function of the same class it's not.

I tried to play with the injection properties, tried to add deps property.

here the relevant parts of my provider class:

```
constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
        private modalService: BsModalService
    ) {
        // here the service is defined and everything is good
        console.log(this.modalService);
    }

    public errorHandler(e?: any) {
        // here the service is undefined
        console.log(this.modalService);
        if (this.modalService.getModalsCount() <= 1) {
            this.modalService.show(NetworkErrorDialogComponent, {initialState: e});
        }
        return of(e);
    }

    public getData(options?: HttpOptions) {
                return this.http.get('path/to/my/api', options).pipe(
                    map(response => response.data || response),
                    catchError(this.errorHandler)
);
            }
```

Comment: What about the HttpClient? Does it behave the same as BsModalService?

Comment: Who's calling the `errorHandler` function? it seems like you changing the `this` context. Just to verify it, console.log or debug inside the errorHandler function. If you `this` is not the class you working on, that's probably your problem.

Comment: I haven't noticed the call to errorHandler. You can change it to: catchError(this.errorHandler.bind(this))

Answer (score 0):

solved it,
I'm transferring the errorHandler to catchError instead of calling it.
this is the solution:

```
catchError(e => this.errorHandler(e))
```